# Convert dataset of discrete changes

Tags: analysis, transformation

Hopefully I'm posting this in the correct community.

I'm trying to get my head around this issue. I've got a discrete dataset containing only 'changes'. It will only record a change of state at a particular time. In the table below the state was  0 for the whole time period between 19:33:14 and 20:18:20. At 20:18:20 it was 1 until 20:19:31 etcetera. Is there any mathematical / numerical way to get a dataset with timestamps (separated by X seconds) vs the amount of time that it was in that state?

I want to transform this dataset into Grafana graphs to observe some energy usages at home.

| Timestamp | State |
| --- | --- |
| 19:33:14 | 0 |
| 20:18:20 | 1 |
| 20:19:31 | 0 |
| 20:20:00 | 1 |
| 20:20:13 | 0 |

edit:
Is is possible in some non-numerical way to obtain the values

| Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 20:20:00 | 1 |
| 20:20:01 | 1 |
| 20:20:02 | 1 |
| 20:20:03 | 1 |
| 20:20:04 | 1 |
| 20:20:05 | 1 |
| 20:20:06 | 1 |
| 20:20:07 | 1 |
| 20:20:08 | 1 |
| 20:20:09 | 1 |
| 20:20:10 | 1 |
| 20:20:11 | 1 |
| 20:20:12 | 1 |
| 20:20:13 | 0 |

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you need a formula to find the time difference between `20:18:20` and `19:33:14`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The formula would be `(TimeNew-TimeOld) x StateOld`  , but I might be overthinking this.    I would like to find out if it is possible to obtain that value on a non-numerical method.